Unable to delete Employee record using LINQ
I am trying to delete a record from Employee table based on EmpId which is the primary key (EmpId is also a foreign key for table Salary) using LINQ in asp.net web Api. But I am getting an error which is:

SQL Exception:
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__Salary__EmpId__3B75D760". The conflict occurred in database "CRUDWithLINQ", table "db. Salary", column 'EmpId.

How can I resolve this?
public bool DeleteEmployee(int id)
{
    
    var employee = (from Employee
                    in _context.Employees
                    where Employee.EmpId == id
                    select Employee).FirstOrDefault();

    if (employee == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var salaries = (from Salary in _context.Salaries//Salaries is entity for Salary
                   where Salary.EmpId == id
                  select Salary).FirstOrDefault();
    var salaries = _context.Salaries.Where(s => s.EmpId == id);

    _context.Salaries.RemoveRange(salaries);
    _context.Employees.Remove(employee);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}


The code is not correct. You can't populate this variable salaries twice with different types. First fix that, then please explain what is not clear about the exception message.

In a real employment records system, you would not ever delete an employee (because their employment history is an auditable fact) and you would not delete salary records (unless those salaries were not ever paid). It may be worth checking that you're taking your software in the right direction.

you need to ensure that the related salary records are deleted before you attempt to delete the employee record.
var salaries = _context.Salaries.Where(s => s.EmpId == id).ToList(); 
if (salaries.Any())
{
   _context.Salaries.RemoveRange(salaries);
}
_context.Employees.Remove(employee);
        
_context.SaveChanges();


Assuming this is Entity Framework, I thought EF would handle table dependency order correctly (top down inserts, bottom-up deletes) as long as the relationships were properly defined in the model. (I don't have a reference handy though.) Perhaps the issue is that the model does not accurately reflect the relationships defined in the database.

you must delete salaries of the employee and save change before deleting employee object.
you can try this :
_context.Salaries.RemoveRange(salaries);
_context.SaveChanges();
_context.Employees.Remove(employee);
_context.SaveChanges();

good luck ;)

Just specify a cascade delete rule on the foreign key.
If you are using a code-first approach you can do it on your db context:
Cascade delete - EF Core
Otherwise directly in the database:
SQL Server delete cascade
Have a look at
